# Hmisc labels in complex plots (SPLOM)

Tags: r, plot, label, psych, hmisc

Is there an easy way how Hmisc labels that have been defined earlier appear in a complex R plot e.g. a SPLOM (scatter plot matrix)?[image]

```
# defining labels
library(Hmisc)
label(mtcars$mpg) <- "Miles per gallon"
label(mtcars$qsec) <- "quarter mile time"

# SPLOM
library(psych)
pairs.panels(mtcars[, c("mpg", "qsec")])
```

In that case instead of "mpg" there should be "miles per gallon" in the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `setNames` to change the names

```
pairs.panels(setNames(mtcars[c("mpg", "qsec")], c("Miles per gallon", "quarter mile time")))
```

[image]